# Atualizações e mudanças na versão do App

Tags: android, atualização

Tenho algumas dúvidas sobre atualizações e mudanças na versão de um aplicativo.

Eu fiz a publicação de um app na Play Store e não alterei nada em meu AndroidManifest. Ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
package="com.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é: como funciona o VersionCode e o VersionName, e, na postagem de uma atualização, quais as alterações que ocorrem nos mesmos? Devo seguir uma ordem numérica? E alguns apps e softwares tem versões do tipo: 1.1.4. Podem me explicar isto?

Valeu!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `versionCode` não é mostrado ao utilizadores e por isso é um numero interno incremental para diferenciar as varias versões, e que permite ao sistema Android não deixar o utilizador instalar um aplicativo com versão inferior ao que já lá está. Da mesma forma também não será possível colocar na Play Store uma versão com um `versionCode` inferior ao que está lá.

As boas práticas dizem que a cada nova versão o `versionCode` deve aumentar de 1 em 1.

O `versionName` é a versão que os utilizadores vem, logo é apenas texto, podendo o programador escrever coisas como:

```
versionName="1.1-demo"
```

Tipicamente este estilo de versões segue o seguinte padrão de nomenclatura:

```
<major>.<minor>.<point>
```

Em que `<major>` é a numeração de versão para quando tem alterações muito grandes, o `<minor>` é quando tem pequenas adições de funcionalidades, e o `<point>` são regra geral só pequenas correções.

Logo de `1.1.14` para `1.1.15` seria apenas pequenas correções de coisas que não tinham ficado corretas.

De `1.1.14` para `1.2` seria uma adição de uma ou outra pequena funcionalidade.

De `1.1` para `2.0` seria uma diferença muito larga e/ou modificação em grande parte das funcionalidades de toda a aplicação, que pode até ser incompatível com versões anteriores.

[Documentação oficial para versões de aplicações pela Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado, não tenho mais dúvidas em relação a isto!